# Why has text editing become garbled in Outlook Web App?

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

Starting about two weeks ago, composing a message in Outlook Web App (OWA) has become a pain.

- Word wrapping has become awry - some lines break early and others span wider than the screen because of which a scroll bar appears at the bottom.
- The cursor jumps arbitrarily. I will be typing and all of a sudden the cursor is somewhere else.
- Ctrl+ behaves unexpectedly.

There has been [an update](http://blogs.office.com/2014/03/11/enhanced-text-editor-in-outlook-web-app/) to OWA whose timing coincides suspiciously with my problems. I am using Firefox 28.0 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Is there a fix to my messaging woes?

Comment: Yes, I've had the same issue. I'm using Firefox on Windows XP/SP3, but I don't see the word wrapping issue in IE and Chrome.

Comment: Apologies, as this is not an answer. I meant to comment, and I can't seem to move this now. Adding a data point to the pile: same issue, started about two days ago. I'm on Mac OS 10.9.2 running Firefox 29.